# Why is Maseches Shekalim in Daf Yomi

Tags: daf-yomi, tractate-shekalim

Why is Maseches Shekalim in Daf Yomi, its from the Yerusahlmi?

Comment: @yoel Why didn't you [vote to close](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) this question as such?

Comment: I heard a Derash yesterday that it is because if someone learns through all of Shas and get's to Shamayim they are going to ask him "why didn't you learn Yerushalmi"? So he can answer "I learned Shekalim" at least one Masechet.

Comment: @HachamGabriel To go to shamayim with only one masechet of yerushalmi under your belt isn't really worth bragging about if you are of the caliber to have completed the rest of Bavli.

Comment: @DoubleAA tell you the truth I didn't like the Derash. There is a very interesting Dibrot Moshe in Kidushin  that might contradict this Derash as well.